# Weblogic 11G : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()

Tags: classloader, weblogic11g

When using Weblogic 11G, I am facing below error.

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1514)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:486)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1912)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:79
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:707)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:4035)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3989)
```

Let me give you more details.
My web application contains **ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar** and **hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar** jar file, among this **hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar** contains **orphanRemoval()** method while **ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar** does not.

I have configured weblogic to load application library instead of weblogic libraries by below specification.

**weblogic-application.xml**

```
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.mozilla.javascript.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.mozilla.classfile.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.persistence.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

So It seems that I need to tell server to load required class from **hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar** instead of **ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar** file but I do not know the way to do that?

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError occur if there is some issue with the jar loaded. I think that on the system that you are trying to run this code on, has **CLASSPATH** set to some path which is loading the older version of the jar. Use the following code to find out the paths from where the ClassLoader is resolving the dependencies

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader)Main.class.getClassLoader();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(classLoader.getURLs()));
    }
```

Put this method in Main class and execute it in the system that is giving this error. It will show you all the paths from where the dependencies have been resolved. Find out if any of the paths have older version of the jar.

Hope this helps your cause.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that on the classpath there is different version of the class which is higher in the classloader hierarchy. Weblogic itself has bunch of libraries embeded to standart weblogic installation. To verify that use -verbose JVM option to see from where the class gets loaded. If thats the case than using weblogic deployment descriptor classloading filtering should solve your issue as you actually do. (as the shiped in libraries sits on system classpath they get precedence to any other lib in your archive). Using this classloading filtering you can break this and get the proper version loaded. I guess different container has different tag. Check with weblogic documentation.

Hope this helps.